# Two servers don't see each other, but both are ok with the others network client

Tags: networking, nas, ping, rsync, synology

I'm trying to synchronize my 2nd synology server (DS1817+) with my main unit (DS3617xs). I will use rsync job thru standard Synology packages.
But I have a network (I guess) problem :

- Assume that I have a Synology Server called A => fixed IP 192.168.1.10
- Another Synology called B => fixed IP 192.168.1.11
- And a developpement server called C => fixed IP 192.168.1.21

Then from C : ping A => OK / ping B => OK

From B : ping A => KO (Destination Host Unreachable) / ping C => OK

From A : ping B => KO (Destination Host Unreachable) / ping C => OK

I don't see any blacklist. And I don't understand why the ping between the two Synology don't work.

Some more informations :

```
A:~$ ifconfig
bond0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:32:66:22:59
      inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fc00::211:32ff:fe66:2259/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fc00::109/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::211:32ff:fe66:2259/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1326308223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:642921303 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:1352896922323 (1.2 TiB)  TX bytes:298255162604 (277.7 GiB)

B:/$ ifconfig
bond0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:32:76:F5:A9
      inet addr:192.168.1.11  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fc00::159/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::211:32ff:fe76:f5a9/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: fc00::211:32ff:fe76:f5a9/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:735498 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:287526 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:128366144 (122.4 MiB)  TX bytes:170445269 (162.5 MiB)
```

===

```
A:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0
169.254.112.1   169.254.119.17  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun1000
169.254.119.17  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1000
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0

B:/$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0
```

What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved !
The problem wasn't in the NAS configuration.
In fact, the LACP configuration in my switch (Linksys LGS318) was enabling "flow control".
Just disabling it and every thing is OK.

Don't really undestand what is flow control in LACP configuration, but it works.

Comment: LACP is Link Aggregation Control Protocol, for using 2 links to increase capacity between switches (or other devices that support it). My guess is there is a duplicate link somewhere, there is a firmware issue in the switch, or the switch just got "stupid" and a reset might have fixed it.

Comment: Maybe the "stupid" option or something like this.
LACP seem to be bad implemented in many device (I had a TP-Link device that lost LACP configuration after each power failure)